# Convergence and continuity except at a point.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a strictly monotone function which is continuous. Then $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$ implies $x_n \rightarrow x.$

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a monotone function which is continuous except at one point say $a.$ Then do we still have $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$ implies $x_n \rightarrow x.$

My answer is "Yes": Since $f$ is strictly monotone it can only have jump discontinuity at $a.$ Without loss of generality assume $f$ is right continuous at $a.$ Since $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x).$ There exists some $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>m$ , either $x_n \in (-\infty, a)$ and $x \in (-\infty, a)$ or $x_n \in [a,\infty)$ and $x \in [a, \infty).$ Now since $f$ is continuous and monotone in each of these sets. Hence $x_n \rightarrow x$ in either of the case.

Is this answer correct?

Comment: By monotone, do you mean strictly monotone? If not, your first assumption isn't valid. $f(x)=0$ is continuous everywhere but "$f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$ implies $x_n \rightarrow x$" isn't valid for this function for example

Comment: Yes it's strictly monotone.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Your first statement is wrong. Assume $$f(x)=x-|x|$$then does $f(x_n)\to 0$ imply $x_n\to x$ for some $x$?

**Remark**

You have this statement true if the function is *strictly* monotone.

Comment: I meant to say $f$ is a strictly monotone. I made a mistake while typing. For $f$ strictly monotone I feel the second statement is true. What do you think?

Comment: Yes. It is true and your proof sounds correct to me